# サイト内からリンクされている英語のブログ記事や、ヘルプセンターの記事一覧

Tags: 討議, プライベートベータ

サイト内の随所に、SE本家の英語のブログ記事や、ヘルプセンターの記事へのリンクがあります。

このうちどれを、どの程度日本語化するかの見通しを立てるため、一度ここに集めたいと思います。

集めた結果、例えば量が少なければ全訳するなどの決定をしたり、優先順位を付けるなどの具体的なプランにつながればと思います。

Comment: @jmac これ、開発者さんにソースコードをgrepで検索してもらうなどして、リンク先のURLだけでも一覧を作ることはできるでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね。多分簡単にできないみたいですが、検討しています。あくまでも、手動でピックアップします。

Answer (score 2):

### ヘルプセンターへのリンク

(現在、これらは翻訳済みです)

- [書式設定のヘルプ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (「書式設定の方法」サイドバー)
- [質問の仕方](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) (「書式設定の方法」サイドバー)
- [回答の仕方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (ユーザープロフィールの「まだどの質問に対しても回答していません」)
- [お礼](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (ユーザープロフィールの「アクティブなお礼はありません」)
- ...

### 英語記事へのリンク

- [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) (質問を投稿する時の「自分の質問に対して回答する」チェックボックス)
- ...

Answer (score 2):

下記の英語ブログ記事のリンクがあります：

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/

Answer (score 2):

プライベートベータの後に追加するのもどうかと思いますが… リンクはしているのでとりあえず

**公式ブログ**

- [jmacさんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/132/15185)
- [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)　
  [重複とマークされている質問があるのはなぜですか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)
- [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
  [タグとはなんですか、どのように機能しますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

---

**その他**

- [tips for getting help.](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/09/tips-for-getting-help-with-your-site.html)  質問の制限
- [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) - (名前だけ)
  [私のアカウントから質問が受け付けられなくなったのは何故ですか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)、質問が受け付けられない状態
- <del>[How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) - [上と同じ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)</del>
  翻訳済みです: [賢い質問の仕方](http://www.ranvis.com/articles/smart-questions.ja.html)
- [How to ask a question](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555375) - [同じ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)　(***機械翻訳済み*** でした、でも翻訳し直したほうが…)
- [1 FAQ tagged with chatfilter](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter) - [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)